# How to set up debugger in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I am new to eclipse and am using it to write C programs for a class. I can't get the debugger to work. I am using a mac and i have install gdb using homebrew and set the paths in eclipse preferences. It doesn't stop at any breakpoints.

this is the error i get

```
 ~"../../gdb/thread.c:95: internal-error: struct thread_info *inferior_thread(): Assertion `c\
urrent_thread_ != nullptr' failed.\nA problem internal to GDB has been detected,\nfurther debugging \
may prove unreliable."
```

Im using macos 11.1
gdb 10.1
eclipse 4.18.0